# What is causing a BUS_ADRALN in [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Our application is occasionally getting a BUS_ADRALN.  Looking at the crash log it shows the line [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil].  I know a BUS_ADRALN is an invalid address, but I'm not seeing the problem.  It works most of the time.

```
    static NSString *buddyListCellId = @"MyCell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:buddyListCellId];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // the following line is what the crash is pointing to
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = buddyListCell;
        self.buddyListCell = nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty straightforward.  What's the code leading up to it?  Perhaps MyCell.nib is corrupt, try a clean and rebuild perhaps (your distribution on the device could be corrupt perhaps)

Comment: Ok, I updated the code to provide the rest of the code.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Eliminate all the cell stuff and see if just that line crashes..?  That is, leave only the [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];